# Replacing an dataframe element's data with the next row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

I have the following dataframe *s*:

```
0  Symbol   DataDiscriminator   Open
1  AKAM     Summary             -
2  AKAM     Lot                 2017-05-12, 16:20:00
3   APA     Summary             -
4   APA     Lot                 2017-03-31, 16:20:00
5   APA     Lot                 2017-03-24, 16:20:00
```

I would like to set the value of *Open* element of *DataDiscriminator* = "Summary" with the date of the next row and then remove the *DataDiscriminator* = "Lot" rows to get:

```
0  Symbol   DataDiscriminator   Open
1  AKAM     Summary             2017-05-12
3   APA     Summary             2017-03-31
...
```

Current working logic is:

```
for i, row in s.iterrows():
    if s.DataDiscriminator[i] == "Summary":
        o = s.Open[i+1]                          # Get the next row's Open data
        s = s.set_value(i, "Open", o[0:10])      # Slice out the time in the new Open data
s = s[s.DataDiscriminator == "Summary"]          # Keep only the Summary rows in the dataset
```

Is there a better vectorized way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shift is the standard vectorized way to do this:

```
>>> df.loc[ df.DataDiscriminator=='Summary','Open'] = df.Open.shift(-1)
>>> df = df[ df.DataDiscriminator=='Summary' ]

  Symbol DataDiscriminator                  Open
0   AKAM           Summary  2017-05-12, 16:20:00
2    APA           Summary  2017-03-31, 16:20:00
```

Comment: Thanks @JohnE. How can I slice out the time component from the *Open* field? `s.loc[ s.DataDiscriminator=='Summary','Open'] = s.Open.shift(-1)[0:10]` gives NaN after a couple of rows in *Open*.

Comment: If it's a string, try `df.Open.str.slice(12)`.  Generally speaking, for strings check the docs for string accessors (`str`).  Or if you have the column stored as a pandas/python datetime, then you could use a datetime accessor (`dt`)

Answer (score 3):

Replace `-` with `None`, backfill with `bfill`, and `query`

```
df.replace(dict(Open={'-': None})).bfill().query('DataDiscriminator != "Lot"')

   0 Symbol DataDiscriminator                  Open
0  1   AKAM           Summary  2017-05-12, 16:20:00
2  3    APA           Summary  2017-03-31, 16:20:00
```

Comment: Ah, yeah, makes more sense to let `bfill` do the combined work of `loc` & `shift` in this case.  But I'll leave my answer as the more obvious approach.  ;-)

Comment: Thank you @piRSquared. Unfortunately, this solution gives **ImportError**: *'numexpr' is not installed or an unsupported version. Cannot use engine='numexpr' for query/eval if 'numexpr' is not installed.* Am I missing something?

Comment: Yeah. You're missing numexpr. (-:  it's what's needed for the query. You can still do the replace and bfill. Just use a Boolean slice afterwards similar to what JohnE did